# Не открывается проект в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр, unity3d-android

он тупо перестал запускаться. в юнити хаб видно, что проект запускается, ибо идет загрузка минут 10, но затем загрузка прекращается, вместе со всеми процессами в диспетчере задач, относящимися к юнити, не считая юнити хаба.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.